# Properties Class Java

Tags: java, properties

How to make a while loop with properties I been 2 days playing with Iterator, toString parse and a lot of another forms here is the format I want to display. Work perfect only for one set of properties so only display the last items from the query.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    String line;
    while((line=in.readLine())!=null){
    System.out.println(line);
    }
```

Display 2 sets in a bad format

Now this is the perfect format but only print the last item:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    String line;
   Properties prop= new Properties();
   while((line=in.readLine())!=null){
  prop.load(in);
   String amount = prop.getProperty("ssl_amount");
    String card = prop.getProperty("ssl_card_number");
    String approval = prop.getProperty("ssl_approval_code");
    String results = prop.getProperty("ssl_result_message");
    String time = prop.getProperty("ssl_txn_time");
    System.out.println(amount+" "+card+" "+approval+" "+results+" "+time+" "); 
  }
```

How I can make a loop to print all the entry's in the correct format?
This is the Raw Input stream:

```
ssl_txn_count=2
ssl_txn_id=071214A15-B805A410-E9F4-4D6D-AA87-0E9923FBC7FA
ssl_user_id=webpage
ssl_trans_status=STL
ssl_card_type=CREDITCARD
ssl_transaction_type=SALE
ssl_txn_time=12/07/2014 11:28:00 PM
ssl_first_name=
ssl_last_name=
ssl_card_number=41**********1111
ssl_exp_date=1115
ssl_entry_mode=K
ssl_avs_response= 
ssl_cvv2_response=P
ssl_amount=10.00
ssl_invoice_number=
ssl_result_message=APPROVAL
ssl_approval_code=CVI064
ssl_txn_id=061214A15-8921B6B0-FF9E-4DA5-97D1-288C28272B10
ssl_user_id=webpage
ssl_trans_status=STL
ssl_card_type=CREDITCARD
ssl_transaction_type=SALE
ssl_txn_time=12/06/2014 01:25:18 AM
ssl_first_name=
ssl_last_name=
ssl_card_number=41**********1111
ssl_exp_date=1215
 ssl_entry_mode=K
 ssl_avs_response= 
 ssl_cvv2_response=P
 ssl_amount=12.00
 ssl_invoice_number=
 ssl_result_message=APPROVAL
 ssl_approval_code=CVI806
```

And here is the good format I want it : (like you can see only report 1 of them and not 2)

```
run:
12.00 41**********1111 CVI806 APPROVAL 12/06/2014 01:25:18 AM 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: can you elaborate what is your meaning of correct format ?

Answer (score 1):

Load the `Reader` once (outside the loop), and then you can iterate the `keySet`. Next, you could display the key and value. Using [Format String Synatx](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) that might look something like,

```
try (InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(
        conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")) {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(is);
    for (Object key : prop.keySet()) {
        System.out.printf("%s=%s%n", key, prop.get(key));
    }
}
```

For hard coded keys (your specific case and if you want to ignore other properties), you don't need a loop

```
try (InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(
        conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")) {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(is);
    String amount = prop.getProperty("ssl_amount");
    String card = prop.getProperty("ssl_card_number");
    String approval = prop.getProperty("ssl_approval_code");
    String results = prop.getProperty("ssl_result_message");
    String time = prop.getProperty("ssl_txn_time");
    System.out.println(amount + " " + card + " " + approval + " "
            + results + " " + time + " ");
}
```

The above are using [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to close the stream(s) when done.

Comment: Only came back with 1 respond. I need the loop to keep going printing the transactions.

Comment: That's not how [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) (or its' superclass [`Hashtable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)) works.

Answer (score 0):

Use Enumuration to iterate property file and here is an example

`Properties prop = new Properties();`

```
InputStream input = nnew FileInputStream("<file-location>.properties");
prop.load(input);
Enumeration<?> e = prop.propertyNames();
while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        String key = (String) e.nextElement();
        String value = prop.getProperty(key);
        System.out.println("Key : " + key + ", Value : " + value);
    }
```

Comment: This came back with all the sets but only for one transaction.